# How do I iterate over the results of a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I'm trying to store all `<a>` elements as objects in array (using `$('a')`), and then get the position of each of them, it doesn't work.

```
years = $('a');
for(i=0;i< years.length;i++){
   if(years[i].position().top > year.position().top){

   }
   else{

   }
}
```

Console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object file:///Users/.../index.html# has no method 'position'

When I do it with single element selected by class name instead of tag name, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Should we guess your JavaScript? Or could you possibly help us to help you, by showing what you've tried?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$("a").each(function() { 
  var pos = $(this).position();
  if (pos.top > year.position().top) {
     // hurray
  }
});
```

Also what is the value of `year`? I prefer to name jQuery objects like this: `var $year = $("#year");` The `$` helps you remember it's a jQuery object.

Comment: year is last clicked <a> element stored as jquery object

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var arr = [], elems = $('a');

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
   arr[i] = elems[i];
}
```

Comment: arr is undefined, you can set no properties of it.