# How can i add the value of input with name attribute?

Tags: jquery

How can I add the value of input with name attribute using jquery? I'm only getting the first input value.

```html
<div class="col-md-12"><label>Question 1 </label></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="faq-page1" id="faq-page1" placeholder="Question 1"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="faq_name" value="1">
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="url" name="faq-url1" id="faq-url1" placeholder="Answer 1"></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><label>Question 2</label></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="faq-page2" id="faq-page2" placeholder="Question 2"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="faq_name" value="1">
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="url" name="faq-url2" id="faq-url2" placeholder="Answer 2"></div>
```

I tried this

```js
var faq_name_value = $("input[name=faq_name]").val();
```

I actually want to add all hidden inputs value.

Comment: Can you share the out, it surely gives you 1 in the console.log(). Also here all the input tag has same name value, you should select either by id or add some class to get differentiated

Answer (score 1):

> I actually want to add all hidden inputs value.

I'd recommend using the following selector to get all the `type="hidden"` `<input>`'s:
<sup>For more info take a look at: [jQuery access input hidden value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376664/jquery-access-input-hidden-value)</sup>

```js
$("input[type=hidden]")
```

Then, we can [loop over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627454/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-results-of-a-jquery-selector) the elements using `.each()`:

**Demo snippet** logging each value:

```js
$("input[type=hidden]").each((i, e) => {
    console.log(e.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12"><label>Question 1 </label></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="faq-page1" id="faq-page1" placeholder="Question 1"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="faq_name" value="1">
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="url" name="faq-url1" id="faq-url1" placeholder="Answer 1"></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><label>Question 2</label></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="faq-page2" id="faq-page2" placeholder="Question 2"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="faq_name" value="1">
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="url" name="faq-url2" id="faq-url2" placeholder="Answer 2"></div>
```

---

If you want to add each value, as in `1+1+5` we'll need to add some more checks to ensure those values are numeric to prevent something like `1+1+abc`.

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number) function to check if the 'value' is numeric.

**Demo snippet** logging the sum of each value:

```js
let total = 0;

$("input[type=hidden]").each((i, e) => {
    if (isNumeric(e.value)) {
        total += parseInt(e.value);
    }
});

console.log('Total: ', total);


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number
function isNumeric(str) {
    if (typeof str != "string") return false 
    return !isNaN(str) && !isNaN(parseFloat(str));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12"><label>Question 1 </label></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="faq-page1" id="faq-page1" placeholder="Question 1"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="faq_name" value="1">
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="url" name="faq-url1" id="faq-url1" placeholder="Answer 1"></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><label>Question 2</label></div>
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="faq-page2" id="faq-page2" placeholder="Question 2"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="faq_name" value="1">
<div class="col-md-12"><input class="form-control" type="url" name="faq-url2" id="faq-url2" placeholder="Answer 2"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="faq_name" value="abc15">
```

Comment: Will break if there are other hidden inputs with different name

Comment: Could you please clarify @charlietfl? Not sure what you mean. Adding something like `<input type="hidden" name="faq_name2" value="5">` give the expected result of `5` next to the already existing elements.

Comment: How about `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="fklw-5577-rrrr"/>`

Comment: Shows `fklw-5577-rrrr` in a `console.log` as expected. Still not sure what 'value' could fail using this method.

Comment: I interpret "add" as `1+1+1=3`. Could be my interpretation is wrong but that was my initial interpretation of the question and OP is specific about targeting `name`

Comment: Ahh, my answer was mostly focused on showing the values, I've added an extra snipping to 'add' the values. If numeric ;)